# Filter access report on subtotals

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'd like to filter my report on the Actual OT(Overtime) subtotal that is more than 30. How can i do it?

Here's the pass-through query to SQL Server:

```
SELECT OT_Entry.App_ID AS OT_Entry_App_ID
, OT_Entry.EmpID
, OT_Entry.EmpName
, OT_Entry.[Pre-Approved_OT]
, OT_Entry.Actual_OT
, tblMain.App_ID AS tblMain_App_ID
, tblMain.Start_Date
, tblMain.End_Date
, tblMain.WO_Number
, tblMain.Plant_Section
, tblMain.Job_Category
, tblMain.[Maint_Area/Section]
, tblMain.[Group/Discipline]
, tblMain.Break_In
, tblMain.Requestor
, tblMain.Justification
, tblMain.Work_Activity
, tblMain.Approver
, tblMain.Request_Date
, EmpData.Position
, EmpData.Reporting_to
, EmpData.Company
, EmpData.Personnel_Type
, EmpData.Group
FROM EmpData INNER JOIN (tblMain INNER JOIN OT_Entry ON tblMain.[App_ID] = OT_Entry.[App_ID]) ON EmpData.EmpID = OT_Entry.EmpID;
```

Below is the screenshot of my report

[Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnMWq.jpg)

Comment: Add a 'where' clause at the end of your SQL:  "WHERE (OT_Entry.Actual_OT > 30)"

Comment: Tied it but it's not working for me, what I did is I grouped using employee ID so all overtime entry under the same ID will be summed up by the subtotal. Since it's a subtotal, the report won't allow me to filter on that or even sort. Is there any other work around using select query? Thanks!

Comment: Create a new query where you group by empid, sum the hours, where clause on your date range. Add that query to your existing query, join on empid, and keep the sum. Each detail record now has the total.